# As a US Citizen, if I'm visiting the Schengen region, can I "work from home"?

Tags: schengen

I'm a US citizen.  I want to spend about 6 weeks vacation visiting my friends in France, Spain and Italy.  However, with taking this much consecutive time off from work my employer would require me to do daily check-ins (email and Skype).

It's also very likely I would have to spend up to 20 hours per week fixing untoward problems.  This would require me logging into my company laptop to write and submit code.  Any hours that I spend doing company work I would be paid as a normal employee (vs. PTO for the rest of the vacation).

Is this legal as a tourist?

EDIT:  I emailed the Spain consulate and received this replay:
As a US citizen you can travel to Spain for up to 90 days without needing a Visa. You could also work for your US employer while visiting Spain.

Comment: Ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange, since this is about work. As a rule of thumb, you can **talk about work** on a Schengen visa, but not **do work**. A business traveler would be expected to check in with home office, after all.

Comment: You'll have to work 20 hours per week on your vacation time?

Comment: @HankyPanky Yes, since I'd be taking 6 straight weeks off.  But any time "on the clock" doesn't go against my PTO

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** no, it is not legal for an US citizen to work in France, Italy and Spain during a visa free stay.

For France it is **explicitly** stated that US citizens need a work permit.

---

**Long answer:**

Almost all **work** based rules are desided on a **country by country** base

- and then often based on the **nationality** of the person

Unfortunately, the official EU summary is an unwieldy excel table for which the wiki link below has a summary of.

Assume that this may **not be up-to-date**, check the countries counsulate sites in your country to make sure that nothing has changed.

---

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area

look for:

- **Rules regarding paid activity during visa-free stay**

the summary above is based on this table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this in the unwieldy excel table confuses me:  "visa requirement on those who wish to enter to work (i.e. to carry out a 'paid activity')".  I would not be entering *to work*, as in I wouldn't be seeking employment within the countries I enter. Am I allowed to work for my US employer?

Comment: As  mentioned in the other link above about the same topic, these rules are **not very realistic for the 21th century workplace**. Work is work with no distinction. Assume the answer is no. Read other comments in the link above.